# How to control other applications Controls

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

Am using SAP , outlook etc.. to analyse the data's

I need to control the Text boxes & Buttons in that application

For ex: I don't want to copy & paste the values in Outlook Search in mail items

Instead I need VBA to paste the values directly into the search text box in outlook and begin searching automatically without giving Copy & Paste manually

In the same way I need to control all Controls of other Applications (Word , SAP etc ) in Excel VBA

Please suggest me some codes

Comment: Are you using vb.net, or VBA?  Your question is pretty broad, so it would help if you could pick just one.  Have you tried searching eg.  "VBA automate outlook"?  There are plenty of examples out there to get you started.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply....am using VBA for Excel .... and one thing i just need to control all other applications controls not just outlook alone ... outlook is just an ex. ... is this possible through API through accessing windows files ... i mean every control would be registered in windows environment .. please suggest me some  codes .. thanks in advance

Comment: In general you'll be limited to applications exposing some kind of com interface. You could possible usecsendkeys for those that don't, but that's a very brittle approach ans one you should avoid.

Comment: Hi Tim .. thanks for your valuable suggestion ... could you provide me some code on how to achieve this using com interface or usecsendkeys so that i can arrive at an conclusion.. thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you try Googling and come back if you have any specific questions?

Answer (score 0):

Prabu Mike,

Just my two cents. I use SAP and Excel as well.
In order to automate a lot of my work, I wrote some AutoHotKey scripts.
The scripts will e.g. read an array from Excel and use the data do populate SAP or create reports from SAP, through the standard SAP admin GUI.

If this is something you would like to know more about, let me know.

Regards,

Robert Ilbrink

Comment: hi thanks robert for your reply .... sorry for the late response.. this is what exactly i need ... can you add little more details like will the array copied from excel will be directly pasted into SAP GUI controls like text box etc... and can i bring that SAP GUI in Active mode ( to be top on all other windows ) through excel

Comment: Mike, send me an email, so I can respond with some sample code that I use. My email is firstname dot lastname at gmail dot com. Regards,